# Passenger Phusion not detecting Rails app under Apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

In an Ubuntu 14.4 environment, am running Passenger under Apache to serve my Rails app.

After starting apache however:

```
$ passenger-status
Version : 5.3.3
Date    : 2018-08-10 17:08:52 -0400
Instance: DZeozT5t (Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/5.3.3)

Phusion Passenger is currently not serving any applications.

$ passenger-config list-instances
Name                       PID      Description
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
DZeozT5t                   1438     Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/5.3.3
```

It seems as if Passenger is installed and happily running, but not detecting my application.

```
$ cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/rails.conf 
<VirtualHost  *:80>
    ServerName url.com
    DocumentRoot /opt/members-only/public
    PassengerRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby
    <Directory "/opt/members-only/public">
        Allow from all
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Options -MultiViews
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My apache user is `www-data`

`/opt/members-only` is a soft link to the deployment directory ( a standard rails app)

```
$ ls -lash /opt/members-only/
total 104K
4.0K drwxrwxr-x 16 www-data www-data 4.0K Aug 10 17:06 .
4.0K drwxr-xr-x 10 platform platform 4.0K Aug 10 16:34 ..
4.0K drwxrwxr-x 11 www-data www-data 4.0K Jul 30 22:22 app
4.0K drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data www-data 4.0K Jul 30 22:22 bin
4.0K drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data www-data 4.0K Jul 30 23:13 .bundle
4.0K drwx------  5 www-data www-data 4.0K Aug 10 16:10 config
4.0K -rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data  130 Jul 30 22:22 config.ru
4.0K drwx------  4 www-data www-data 4.0K Jul 30 22:22 db
4.0K drwxrwxr-x  3 www-data www-data 4.0K Jul 30 22:22 doc
4.0K -rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data 2.3K Aug 10 15:45 Gemfile
8.0K -rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data 6.3K Aug 10 15:45 Gemfile.lock
4.0K drwxrwxr-x  4 www-data www-data 4.0K Jul 30 22:22 lib
4.0K drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data www-data 4.0K Aug 10 16:12 log
4.0K drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 4.0K Aug 10 16:33 node_modules
4.0K -rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data   70 Jul 30 22:22 package.json
4.0K drwxrwxr-x  4 www-data www-data 4.0K Aug 10 16:13 public
4.0K -rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data  227 Jul 30 22:22 Rakefile
4.0K -rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data  374 Jul 30 22:22 README.md
4.0K drwxrwxr-x  3 www-data www-data 4.0K Jul 30 23:13 vendor
4.0K -rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   86 Aug 10 16:33 yarn.lock
```

There are no passenger related errors in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

How can I get passenger to detect my application?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. When going through this step by step deployment:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04

I realized that I had not disabled the default site or enabled mine:

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default
sudo a2ensite testapp
sudo service apache2 restart
```